# Installing GD on Centos 6.3

Tags: php, centos, installation, yum, gd

Hello everyone I am trying to enable GD in my installation of PHP in my CentOS 6.3 machine running lighttpd as the web server. I have done `yum install gd gd-php` and when I run `php -i` I get

```
    gd
    GD Support => enabled
    GD Version => bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
    FreeType Support => enabled
    FreeType Linkage => with freetype
    FreeType Version => 2.3.11
    GIF Read Support => enabled
    GIF Create Support => enabled
    JPEG Support => enabled
    libJPEG Version => 6b
    PNG Support => enabled
    libPNG Version => 1.2.49
    WBMP Support => enabled
    XPM Support => enabled
    XBM Support => enabled`
```

So it is definitely there, `php -m` also shows gd but then when I run `phpinfo();` There is no section for GD and under Configure Command I have this: `--without-gd`.

What are my options here? I've tried removing and reinstalling rpms, restarting lighttpd, other repositories and all sorts of things but no luck... any ideas? I am trying to setup a CMS that uses GD and I can't proceed with the installation because I don't have GD.

Comment: Seems like a multiple php install.

Answer (score 2):

The gd-php adds the php module for gd. It is not compiled into php, which is why you see the --without-gd in the info.

It sounds like you never restarted lighttpd or php-fpm (if that is how you set it up).

I have seen instances where a simple restart of lighttpd won't kill the php-fcgi threads, which cause it to use the old php configuration even after `service lighttpd restart`. So if a simple restart fails, do a full stop, ensure that no php processes are running, and start it back up.

Comment: Awesome thanks!! I killed all the php processes manually and then rebooted my server and GD magically showed up! Thank you!